# What can we do about the indecomposable representations of wild quivers and wild algebras?

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

I know that using finite number of parameters we can not describe indecomposable modules of wild quivers, but is it possible for us to describe them using infinitely many parameters for at least some cases?

Comment: This has been solved here on MathOverflow by Lieven Le Bruyn:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/213068/is-it-possible-to-classify-the-indecomposable-representations-of-the-wild-quiver

Comment: I suggest we should close this question since it already has been solved on MathOverflow..